# Javascript diamond? (Less than followed by greater than)

Tags: javascript

In the following code snippet (from [A List Apart Alternative Style: Working With Alternate Style Sheets - Snippet 8](http://alistapart.com/article/alternate#snippet8)) what does the `<i>` mean inside of the for loop's termination condition statement? I've never seen this notation in JavaScript before. I can kind of assume what it does but I'd like a more definitive answer.

```
function getActiveStyleSheet() {
    var i, a;
    for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")<i>); i++) {
        if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1
            && a.getAttribute("title")
            && !a.disabled) return a.getAttribute("title");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a typo in the article. It should read

```
for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
```

Also that's terrible code and you should seek out an alternative tutorial.

*edit* — good grief, that article is 13 years old.  It might as well be written in Latin.